# How to switch between two Apache installations?

Tags: apache

Some time ago I installed Apache 2.2.29 with this manual:
https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew 
into this directory: 
*/usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/httpd*

Yesterday I installed Apache 2.4.17 with this manual:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV52Vs4E1xs
into this directory:
*/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd*

Terminal command 
which httpd
shows me this:
Server version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)

is there any way to switch to 2.4.17?
(I'm on OS X 10.10.5)

Comment: you can try with both port numbers;
Ex: http://localhost:80 and http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. Just specify the absolute path.

For example to stop Apache 2.2.9 use the following command:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/apachectl -k stop
```

Give it a few seconds or use 'ps' to check its finished shutting down and then use the following to start up the 2.4.17 instance:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Note when you machine restarts it my revert to the old version depending what's in its start up scripts.

Also any config will be specific to each installation so you might find they don't point to the same DocumentRoot so don't display the same website.

You cannot run both under port 80 at the same time. However you could run one under port 80 and one under another port of you wanted both running at exactly the same time.

Comment: I did what you told me, but with „sudo”. After stopping 2.2.29 and starting 2.4.17 I typed „which httpd” and I've got „/usr/sbin/httpd”. Under this directiory I found alias to httpd 2.2.29 exec file and I replaced it with alias to httpd 2.4.17 exec file. After this replacement I typed „httpd -v” and I've got „Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix). Thanks!